# Free falling elevator question

Tags: reference-frames, inertial-frames

The question is about inertial and non-inertial frame of references.

The question:

[image: Question]

And my solution for this question:

[image: Answer]

My question about this problem is, what if $\vec{a}_{0} < \vec{g}$? Then would not the mass fall to the floor?

Comment: The local value of the acceleration of free fall (relative to the elevator) will be $\vec g -\vec a_{\rm o}$.

Comment: When the problem says "the *falling* elevator" probably it means that the elevator is in free fall, so that $\vec{a}_0 = \vec{g} $. In this case, the object will not fall to the floor. But if the elevator is not in free fall, then your observation is right.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when ${\vec a_o}<{\vec g}$, the object will definitely fall to the floor. The question is incorrect. In the non-inertial frame, the ball will fall as long as there is a net acceleration downwards. However, the mass will take more time to fall as compared to on ground.